# Why is the C# compiler using the parent type of a value returned by an implicit operator to invoke overloaded operators

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public static Parent operator +(Parent l, Parent r)
    {
        return new Parent(); //do something meaningful
    }
}

public class Child: Parent
{
    public static Child operator +(Child l, Parent r)
    {
        return new Child(); //do something meaningful, child related
    }
}
```

Then I have a wrapper class that uses `implicit` conversion to return the wrapped value:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    private T value;

    public T Value => value;

    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper.value;
    }
}
```

Then I am combining the 2 as follows:

```
public class Usage
{
    private Parent someField;
    private Wrapper<Child> wrappedValue;

    public void UseOperatorWithImplicitConversion()
    {
        //Child sum1 = wrappedValue + someField; //<-- compilation error
        Parent sum2 = wrappedValue + someField;

        Child temp = wrappedValue; //works but defeats the purpose of reduced verbosity
        Child sum3 = temp + someField;
    }
}
```

I was expecting the `sum1` line to work. I had a look in the generated IL and it seems that the types are there:

```
IL_0001: ldarg.0      // this
IL_0002: ldfld        class Example.Wrapper`1<class Example.Child> Example.Usage::wrappedValue
IL_0007: call         !0/*class Example.Child*/ class Example.Wrapper`1<class Example.Child>::op_Implicit(class Example.Wrapper`1<!0/*class Example.Child*/>)
IL_000c: ldarg.0      // this
IL_000d: ldfld        class Example.Parent Example.Usage::someField
IL_0012: call         class Example.Parent Example.Parent::op_Addition(class Example.Parent, class Example.Parent)
IL_0017: stloc.0      // sum2
```

Though the `IL_0012` is a call to `op_Addition` of the `Parent` and not the `Child`.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 C# 7.2

Comment: I would say that compiler first selects one of available `operator +` candidates (see the [binary operator overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-operator-overload-resolution) section of language specification) and uses the first one which it can make work.

Comment: @GuruStron but then I would expect that if I remove the operator overload from `Parent` then it would compile as the second best is the one from `Child`. That's not the case, I still get the error.

Comment: Yes, it is true, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not consider every possible user defined operator overload from every single class when trying to determine which operator overload to call in a particular situation.  It only considers operator overloads defined in the (compile time) types of one of the operands.  It doesn't consider operators defined in every type that any of the operands has an implicit conversion to.

Answer (score 0):

***I think that @Servy's answer is correct. I just want to extend it by providing links to C# specification and adding an explanation.***

[Binary operator overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-operator-overload-resolution) is used to determine a set of candidate operators:

> An operation of the form `x op y`, where `op` is an overloadable binary
>   operator, `x` is an expression of type `X`, and `y` is an expression of type
>   `Y`, is processed as follows:
>
> - The set of candidate user-defined operators provided by `X` and `Y` for
>     the operation `operator op(x,y)` is determined. The set consists of the
>     union of the candidate operators provided by `X` and the candidate
>     operators provided by `Y`, each determined using the rules of [Candidate
>     user-defined operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#candidate-user-defined-operators). If `X` and `Y` are the same type, or if `X` and `Y`
>     are derived from a common base type, then shared candidate operators
>     only occur in the combined set once.
> - (Other items are not important)

In this line of code

```
Parent sum2 = wrappedValue + someField;
```

`x` is an expression of type `Wrapper<Child>` and `y` is an expression of type `Parent`.

According to the rules of binary operator overload resolution a set of candidate operators is a union of the operators provided by these two types. For each of this types a set of candidate operators is determinded by using rules [Candidate user-defined operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#candidate-user-defined-operators):

> Given a type `T` and an operation `operator op(A)`, where `op` is an
>   overloadable operator and `A` is an argument list, the set of candidate
>   user-defined operators provided by `T` for `operator op(A)` is determined
>   as follows:
>
> - For all `operator op` declarations in `T` and all lifted forms of such operators, if at least one operator is applicable ([Applicable
>     function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#applicable-function-member)) with respect to the argument list `A`, then the set of
>     candidate operators consists of all such applicable operators in `T`.
> - (Other items are not important)

and [Applicable function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#applicable-function-member):

> A function member is said to be an applicable function member with
>   respect to an argument list `A` when all of the following are true:
>
> - For each argument in `A`, the parameter passing mode of the argument (i.e., `value`, `ref`, or `out`) is identical to the parameter passing mode
>     of the corresponding parameter, and
>
>   - for a value parameter or a parameter array, an implicit conversion ([Implicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-conversions)) exists from the argument to the type
>       of the corresponding parameter.
>   - (Other items are not important)

Using these rules we can conclude the following:

- For type `Wrapper<Child>` a set of candidate operators for operation `operator +(Wrapper<Child>, Parent)` is empty.
- For type `Parent` a set of candidate operators for operation `operator +(Wrapper<Child>, Parent)` consists of a single operator defined in `Parent`: `operator +(Parent, Parent)`. This operator is applicable (according to the [Applicable function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#applicable-function-member)) as a candidate operator because there is an implicit conversion from `Wrapper<Child>` to `Parent`.

***So we have one candidate operator `operator +(Parent, Parent)` therefore it is applied in our case.***

***Also we can conclude the following:***

- A set of the candidate operators is defined only for actual types of the operands used in the operation. Types to which operands can be implicitly converted are not taken into account in this process. Therefore `operator +(Child, Parent)` from the class `Child` was not considered as a candidate operator.
- Implicit conversion is used when defining if an operator is applicable to its arguments. Therefore `operator +(Parent, Parent)` was defined as applicable for the case `operator +(Wrapper<Child>, Parent)`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to elaborate. I've read the spec when another user linked it. Though I see `op_Implicit` is called first  in `IL_0007` and then `op_Addition`. I would expect that the compiler knows the types at that time, no?

Comment: Compiler knows that there is an implicit conversion of `Wrapper<Child>` to `Child`, but according to the specification this implicit conversion is not used when forming a set of candidate operators. Compiler looks for candidate operators only in the classes `Wrapper<Child>` and `Parent` that are used in the operation, and it doesn't look for candidate operators in the classes to which operands `Wrapper<Child>` and `Parent` can be implicitly converted.

Comment: Therefore when you comment or delete `operator +` in `Parent` class your code does not compile. Because compiler does not consider `operator +` from `Child` as a candidate operator for operation `Parent sum2 = wrappedValue + someField;` from your sample.

Comment: Yes that last part of _when_ the implicit operator is used in the resolution process and it doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: You are right. Impicit conversion is used to make `operator +(Parent, Parent)` applicable to operation `Parent sum2 = wrappedValue + someField;`.

Comment: In the  `Applicable function member` of the document you've linked, second bullet, first sub-bullet: _[...]for a value parameter or a parameter array, **an implicit conversion exists** from the argument to the type of the corresponding parameter[...]_ emphasis mine.  So unless I'm misinterpreting the spec, the implicit conversions apply _during_ the applicable function member process and not after.

Comment: I think that it is better to say that implicit conversions are used to define (not applied) if current argument (`Wrapper<Child>` in our case) can be implicitly converter to the corresponding argument of the target function (`Parent`). You are right, implicit conversion are applied during applicable function member process. But what do you mean by saying "not after"?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev it kind of works with build in operators: `public class MyClass{public static implicit operator int(MyClass c)=> 1;}` and `double x = new MyClass() + 1`

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, you are right. For your sample (`new MyClass() + 1`) the second bullet from [Binary operator overload resolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-operator-overload-resolution) is applied. There is no a user defined operator for operation `new MyClass() + 1`, but there is a predefined operator [`operator +(int, int)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#addition-operator), and this operator is considered and applied as a candidate operator.

Comment: I mean during `Applicable function member` and not after it. :) Your answer implies that implicit conversion takes place _after_ not _during_ the applicable function member resolution.

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis May be my explanation of this part was not clear, but I wanted to express that exactly during the `Applicable function member` process implicit conversions are used. I edited my answer. I hope now it clearly describes that implicit conversions are used during `Applicable function member` process and not after :)